# RxJava Alternate to CompletableFuture

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am new to Rx java and trying to find a solution to my problem. I want to return a Single to caller but the data is not available when that method is called, it will get filled either before that call is made or after that call is made. A naive example of what I am trying to do is below. CompletableFuture partially solves it but I am looking for Rx solution, possibly with backpressure.

```
val receiver = Receiver()

class Receiver {
    var data = ""

    // this returns a single but does not have data, but will be available after call to onComplete
    request(): Single<Data> {
        return Single.fromFuture(completableFuture)
    }

    onNext(data: String) {
        data.append(data)
    }

    onComplete() {
        completableFuture.complete(data)
    }
}

class Processor {
    fun process() {
        receiver.onNext("1")
        receiver.onNext("2")
        receiver.onComplete()
    }
}

class Caller {
    fun call() {
        // This should get "12" result
        // Processor().process() can be called before or after caller subscibe
        receiver.request()..subscribe(...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `CompletableFuture`, you can use `PublishSubject`. In order to be able to supply the value either before or after the subscribe call, you should also used `.cache()` on the `Single`. Put it all together like this:

```
class Receiver {
    var data = ""
    val subject = PublishSubject.create<Data>()
    val single = Single.fromObservable(subject).cache()
    // this ensures there is at least one subscription when the event is published - otherwise because there is no subscriber, the event is lost, despite cache().
    val dummyObserver = single.subscribe()

    // this returns a single but does not have data, but will be available after call to onComplete
    fun request(): Single<Data> {
        return single
    }

    fun onNext(data: String) {
        // as before
    }

    fun onComplete() {
        subject.onNext(data)
        subject.onComplete(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but that did not work for me.
init {
single.subscribe({ // won't print data})
publishSubject.subscribe {// prints expected data}
}

Comment: also to add call to "request" may happen after call to "onComplete"

Comment: I've added a fix - I'd forgotten `onComplete()`, but even with that `cache()` doesn't create a subscription, so it doesn't remember any values that the `PublishSubject` sends if the subscriber has not subscribed already. I couldn't find a more elegant way around the problem than creating a dummy subscription; this ensures the `Single.cache()` works correctly.

Comment: I haven't added the clean-up code for the `dummyObserver()` - you will need to call `dispose()` on it at an appropriate time.

Comment: based on your solution I made small modification that worked for me is to instead use BehaviorSubject. and add take(1) to single without needing to call onComplete. val single = Single.fromObservable(behaviorSubject.take(1))

Comment: Nice, `BehaviourSubject` is much cleaner. I prefer the explicit `onComplete()` call to using `take(1)`, because it will help flush out any bugs if you do happen to send a second value to the subject.

Comment: using onComplete and not take(1) did not work. I think issue was again because of not subscribing before onComplete call.